# AWS CodeBuild - Environment based off of image from docker hub

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerhub, aws-codebuild

Quick question and this may be a dumb one. I am attempting to use AWS Code Build with an image I've published to Docker Hub. I selected the option to use a custom image, and the the option to look for the image in another location (an external image repo).

I can't seem to figure out how to reference my image in the appropriate format to use it in the other location field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Below is the field I'm looking to complete:]

Answer (score 7):

In the "Other location" text box you can enter the image name from DockerHub. For example, simply give "openjdk" or "openjdk:latest" to use https://hub.docker.com/r/library/openjdk/ as the Docker image for your build. Don't put the "docker pull " prefix for your image name is all.

Note that CodeBuild only supports public Docker images from DockerHub today. Private registries are not supported.

Comment: It threw me off since it has a "repository / docker image name" prompt in the field, but it does actually work to just put in something like "node:11" for the node docker image build for version 11. I guess docker hub is the default docker repository.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say that you published your image in hub.docker.com, and your repo name is `gjackson/myrepo`, and you want to grab the image tagged `latest`, you should populate the other location field with `docker.io/gjackson/myrep:latest`.